# How to determine which regions, each defined by longitude , latitude and a radius, contain a given location?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, geo

I have a large data set of regions , each of which is defined by a longitude, latitude and a given radius.  I have a location point with a  a latitude and longitude and I need to determine  which of the regions contains  my point.

Currently I am using brute force : I compute the distance between the target point and  each region's center longitude and latitude ; if the distance is less than the radius of the region, I include the region in in my result.
Obviously this solution is not tenable.

Can GeoHash be used to formulate a solution ?

Edit : The business problem is given a set of cell phone with known ranges and a fixed set of  available locations owned by a real estate holding, where is the place for a signal repeater.  There are other considerations of course besides location and distance. Otherwise someone will have drive around the country with a signal detection kit -- not optimal . Not a homework question. I have Comp Sci background but GIS is new to me and I am willing to learn.

Edit : I will continue using brute force across several ec2 instances. Not the most optimum solution but it works. Thank you all for proposed solutions but unfortunately given the time and knowledge constraints and vagueness of the methodology, I am not going to be able to try them out.

Comment: What language? Java,C++,SQL etc?

Comment: i donot care about language as much as algorithm for this problem

Comment: The language defines what maths functions can be used.

Comment: Just curious: for what kind of project you need that?

Comment: how often you need the calculation? one time, ore once a second. if once, then a brute force approach may also work, saving a lot of money.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to use a spatial index like quad tree or kd tree.
To this index you add the rectangular bounds of all circles to build up the index.

Uisng the quad tree:
Query the index which objects overlap a quad node at given position. The result will be some circles , these you check as you described.

quad trees don't like the deletion of elements.

Comment: I like quadtrees:  If I am understanding your approach,  I should create a bounded area for the circular regions, create quadtrees for the regions -- index those regions with quadttree keys and  then to determine  which regions contains the location, I should create a quadtree keey for the location and use that to query the index ? Will this work.

Comment: bounding regions are rectangles. each rectangle get an id or array position. add the rectangle to the quad with key = id; quad.add(Rect, 26); where 26 is the key of the rectangöle (e-.g array pos) later List foundObjects = quad.find(lat, lon);

Comment: You don't need the quad key in your application. you query the quad tree with a lat,lon and get back a list of objects near to lat/lon. (or depending of your find() method you get back a list of object where the  position is inside.

Comment: @Phpdna I am experienced in quad trees. He does not need the adjacent thing. He wants to know which objects contains the point, and for that the Rectangle Quad tree is one of the best solutions (equal to R-tree which is much more complicated to implement)  Don't forget there are a high number of different quad  trees. (Point Qwuad tree, bucket based, region based, MX, MX-CIF, PMR. PR, etc.. I have implemented that for a professional automotive device. read Hannan Sammet: Foundation of Multidimensional Metric data Structures.